# TensorFlow Extended installing error with some conficts

Tags: python-3.x, pip, tensorflow2.0, tfx, tensorflow-extended

I need help installing tfx, I just ran this command:

```
pip install -U tfx
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install tfx==0.13.0, tfx==0.14.0, tfx==0.15.0, tfx==0.21.0, tfx==0.21.1, tfx==0.21.2, tfx==0.21.3, tfx==0.21.4, tfx==0.21.5, tfx==0.22.0, tfx==0.22.1, tfx==0.22.2, tfx==0.23.0 and tfx==0.23.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tfx 0.23.1 depends on tensorflow-data-validation<0.24 and >=0.23.1
    tfx 0.23.0 depends on tensorflow-data-validation<0.24 and >=0.23
    tfx 0.22.2 depends on pyarrow<0.17 and >=0.16
    tfx 0.22.1 depends on pyarrow<0.17 and >=0.16
    tfx 0.22.0 depends on pyarrow<0.17 and >=0.16
    tfx 0.21.5 depends on ml-metadata<0.22 and >=0.21.2
    tfx 0.21.4 depends on ml-metadata<0.22 and >=0.21.2
    tfx 0.21.3 depends on ml-metadata<0.22 and >=0.21.2
    tfx 0.21.2 depends on tfx-bsl<0.22 and >=0.21.3
    tfx 0.21.1 depends on ml-metadata<0.22 and >=0.21.2
    tfx 0.21.0 depends on tfx-bsl<0.22 and >=0.21
    tfx 0.15.0 depends on tensorflow-data-validation<0.16 and >=0.15
    tfx 0.14.0 depends on tensorflow-data-validation<0.15 and >=0.14.1
    tfx 0.13.0 depends on tensorflow-data-validation<0.14 and >=0.13.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

I don't know why and how to fix it.
I also tried without `-U` tag and didn't work though.

In advanced, thanks you so much for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this issue which is already addressed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/3794) and try with pip install -i https://pypi-nightly.tensorflow.org/simple/ tfx and let us know if you still face an issue. Thanks